# Apps still say I have previous version of PHP even though I have updated to 5.6

Tags: 14.04, php, lamp, wordpress, nextcloud

As of this morning, I had a LAMP stack set up on my VPS with Ubuntu 14.04 php 5.5.9 and my sql version 5.5.53. I use this LAMP stack solly for hosting a couple of websites but I also want to use it for [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/). The first thing I did was install nextcloud as I want to set up a home server and I was prompted with the message:

> This version of Nextcloud requires at least PHP 5.6.0 You are
>   currently running 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20. Please update your PHP version.

Consiquently, I updated my PHP to 5.6 following this method using a non root user with sudo privileges:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip
```

Everything worked ok and when I run `php -v` in the command line I get:

```
PHP 5.6.29-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

So far so good however when I try to access nextcloud I am still greeted with the same message I got before upgrading php saying that I am running php 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20. Furthermore, when I use a 'system status' plugin on my wordpress website theme it also says that I am running php 5.5.9.

So my question is this, even though I have updated php to 5.6 on my vps, why do apps like wordpress and nextcloud seem to think that I am still on 5.5.9? how can I fix this?

Comment: You also need to install the Apache module for PHP 5.6; I'll let you figure out whih package it is in.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after fkraiem's comment I have done some digging and once I disabled the PHP5 module and then enabled the PHP5.6 module everything worked. I ran the following in the command line:

```
sudo a2dismod php5
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Thanks for the help in pointing me in the right direction :)